# selecting multiple images from gallery Android

Tags: android, android-gallery

i am trying to select multiple images from gallery and upload them and this error appears to me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/file/14844/ORIGINAL/NONE/827721333 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Ffile%2F14844/ORIGINAL/NONE/827721333 ...} }} to activity {com.foksart.fixawyBeta/com.foksart.fixawyBeta.ChangeOrder}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3778)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3821)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665)
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799)
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689)
                  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
                     at android.content.res.HwResources.getText(HwResources.java:1473)
                     at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:298)
                     at com.foksart.fixawyBeta.ChangeOrder.onActivityResult(ChangeOrder.java:734)
                     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6602)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3774)
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3821) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:168) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428) 
                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150) 
                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5665) 
                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:799) 
                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:689)
```

and my code for the activity result is this

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        ArrayList<Object> paths=new ArrayList<>();
              paths.add(data.getStringArrayListExtra("data"));
Toat.makeText(this,paths.size(),Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

and i am using this upload function

```
public void uploadFile(ArrayList<String> imgPaths) {

    String charset = "UTF-8";

    File sourceFile[] = new File[imgPaths.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < imgPaths.size(); i++) {
        sourceFile[i] = new File(imgPaths.get(i));
    }
    try {
        FileUploader multipart = new FileUploader(uploadUrl, charset);

        multipart.addHeaderField("User-Agent", "CodeJava");
        multipart.addHeaderField("Test-Header", "Header-Value");

        multipart.addFormField("description", "Cool Pictures");
        multipart.addFormField("keywords", "Java,upload,Spring");

        for (int i = 0; i < imgPaths.size(); i++) {
            multipart.addFilePart("uploaded_file[]", sourceFile[i]);
        }

        List<String> response = multipart.finish();

        System.out.println("SERVER REPLIED:");

        for (String line : response) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

and the file uploader file

```
public class FileUploader {
private final String boundary;
private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
private String charset;
private OutputStream outputStream;
private PrintWriter writer;

public FileUploader(String requestURL, String charset)
        throws IOException {
    this.charset = charset;

    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";

    URL url = new URL(requestURL);
    httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
    httpConn.setDoOutput(true); // indicates POST method
    httpConn.setDoInput(true);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "CodeJava Agent");
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Test", "Bonjour");
    outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
    writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset),
            true);
}

/**
 * Adds a form field to the request
 * @param name field name
 * @param value field value
 */
public void addFormField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + name + "\"")
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=" + charset).append(
            LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}

/**
 * Adds a upload file section to the request
 * @param fieldName name attribute in <input type="file" name="..." />
 * @param uploadFile a File to be uploaded
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void addFilePart(String fieldName, File uploadFile)
        throws IOException {
    String fileName = uploadFile.getName();
    writer.append("--" + boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(
            "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + fieldName
                    + "\"; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"")
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(
            "Content-Type: "
                    + URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(fileName))
            .append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();

    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFile);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesRead = -1;
    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    outputStream.flush();
    inputStream.close();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}

/**
 * Adds a header field to the request.
 * @param name - name of the header field
 * @param value - value of the header field
 */
public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
    writer.append(name + ": " + value).append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.flush();
}

/**
 * Completes the request and receives response from the server.
 * @return a list of Strings as response in case the server returned
 * status OK, otherwise an exception is thrown.
 * @throws IOException
 */
public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
    List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();

    writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
    writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
    writer.close();

    // checks server's status code first
    int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                httpConn.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.add(line);
        }
        reader.close();
        httpConn.disconnect();
    } else {
        throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
    }

    return response;
}
```

}

Comment: "and my code for the activity result is this" -- no, it is not. Or, perhaps, that is a different `onActivityResult()` than the one that is crashing. You are crashing on call to `Toast.makeText()`, as you can tell by reading your stack trace. You have not shown this `makeText()` call in any of the source code in your question.

Comment: i missed adding this but it says that the paths array is a null object

Comment: So you found your answer. Your Array is null. Check why is it to and you'll find your solution.

Comment: @DavidK how to get the list of paths of the images selected

Comment: Check your answer below, it might be that Toast does not want to print the integer out. Try what he suggested, if it does not work, then check why is your Array empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
Toat.makeText(this,paths.size(),Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
```

This is not your code, as this will not compile (and, even if it did courtesy of odd imports, it would not give the results shown in the stack trace). If you are going to ask questions on Stack Overflow, provide **the actual code that is crashing**, that matches up with the stack trace.

However, if we fix this to be:

```
Toast.makeText(this,paths.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

then we get something that matches the crash:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

`paths.size()` is an `int`. The `makeText()` method that takes an `int` for the message expects that to be a string resource ID, and yours is not.

Generally, for debugging, you are better served logging messages to LogCat:

```
Log.e("Something Eye-Catching", String.format("paths.size(): %d", paths.size()));
```

If you want to stick with the `Toast`, pass in a `String`, not an `int`:

```
Toast.makeText(this,String.format("paths.size(): %d", paths.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or:

```
Toast.makeText(this, Integer.toString(paths.size()),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Maybe just add also that he should make sure that the paths Array is indeed not empty!

Comment: @DavidK: If `paths` were empty, the error would be different, complaining about `0x0` not being a valid resource, instead of `0x1`. So, at least for the stack trace in the question, we know that `paths` has a `size()` of `1`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see in detail stacktrace.. I just read that the OP has null object  reference issue.

Comment: thank you for your contribution it solved my first problem but i can't get the actual paths of images

Comment: @AssemMahrous: I know of no `Intent` that returns a result with `ArrayList<String>` in a `data` extra. You might consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, with the actual code for your `startActivityForResult()` call and the actual code for the corresponding `onActivityResult()` method, and explain that you are having difficulty working with the result.